# order results by category, wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a category page called 'features' this is all fine, but the posts in the features category also belong to a certain genre of film, and it's this what I want to order the posts by on the actual features category template.

eg

features cat template brings in all features posts.

then what I want to do is display in alpha order by whatever genre it also belongs to

```
features
      action
         post
         post
         post
      comedy
         post
         post
       sci-fi
         post
         post
```

etc.

this is what I have at the moment ( the cat numbers relate to the genres = action=10 etc)

```
query_posts('cat=10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18&orderby=title&order=DESC' );
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

How can I list all the posts (group them) by genre ? when I use title here i guess it's using the posts title.

Playing around if I stick this in the post loop

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) {
    if (cat_is_ancestor_of(4, $childcat)) {
        echo $childcat->cat_name;

    }
}
```

this returns the actual genre cat for each post while in the loop, but I'm not sure how to stick it together so I can state the ordering of the posts by groups of genre, I was hoping I could do this in the query_posts?

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider first doing a query for your sub categories, and then loop through your sub categories querying the posts for each. Like so:

```
$categories =  get_categories( array ( 'child_of' => 10, 'orderby' => 'name' ) );
foreach( $categories as $category ){
    // query_posts for category by $category->term_id
    // Display posts for this category
}
```

Does that work for what you are wanting to do?